# Best linux distro

Tags: linux

I'm new on linux =. can someone tell me about what is the best linux distro full of free applications ?

Comment: No, it's too much a matter of taste.

Comment: Think of linux as a tool. Each job has a tool that works best for it. What are you trying to accomplish? If you are just looking for experience, I started with Ubuntu. Just grab one and go...

Comment: Thanks for your answers I'm looking for beautiful overview and graphism, also I'm gonna use it for programming with GFortran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All distros have a lot of free apps. Seriously, most of the apps are free. If I were you, I would test some distros (for at least two weeks), maybe two or three paralel, and then decide by my own taste. There is no generally best distro, but you have chance to find the best distro for you.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes I'll try some but you mean by virtual machine ?

Comment: Even vm's are good to compare them, but the distros advantages and disadvantages could be more easy to find under real usage. I think about a good way to choose: take a bunch of distros, install them into vm's then take the three or four of them which are of your taste and test those on a real machine. The bootloader gives you the possibility to choose the installed OS you want to load.